# window.scrollTop is undfined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

why would `window.scrollTop` be undefined?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

> The Element.scrollTop property gets or sets the number of pixels that
> an element's content is scrolled vertically.
>
> An element's scrollTop value is a measurement of the distance from the
> element's top to its topmost visible content. When an element's
> content does not generate a vertical scrollbar, then its scrollTop
> value is 0.

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if(window.scrollTop > 0) {
            console.log('of the top')
            console.log('scroll top value is: ' + window.scrollTop)
        } else {
            console.log('the top')
            console.log('scroll top value is: ' + window.scrollTop)
        }
    })
```

All I'm getting in my console log is:

`scroll top value is: undefined`

and I'm always getting an evaluation of in the if else:

`of the top`

even if I'm scrolled to the top of the page.

Why would window.scrollTop be undefined?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop does window not count as an element?

Comment: Try making window variable , a global var

Comment: You've answered the question by yourself: "_does window not count as an element?_" That's it, `window` is not an element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY , or use `scrollTop` method of jQuery.

Comment: @teemu window is an object right?

Comment: Yes, it's an object, but not an element. Detecting the scrolling position depends on the environment (at least it was) in some browsers you check it from `document.body`, or in some browsers you check it from `document.documentElement`. jQuery has normalized the behavior in `scrollTop` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery $ identifier as well as the parenthesis () for .scrollTop() in order to get the position

Here's the executable code:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            console.log('of the top')
            console.log('scroll top value is: ' + $(window).scrollTop())
        } else {
            console.log('the top')
            console.log('scroll top value is: ' + $(window).scrollTop())
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> <script>
> jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
>         if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
>             console.log('of the top')
>             console.log('scroll top value is: ' + $(window).scrollTop())
>         } else {
>             console.log('the top')
>             console.log('scroll top value is: ' + $(window).scrollTop())
>         }
>     })
> </script>
> ```

YESSINE's code is correct. but can make it simple

```
<script>
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var window = $(window);
        if(window.scrollTop() > 0) {                
            console.log('of the top')
            console.log('scroll top value is: ' + window.scrollTop())
        } else {
            console.log('the top')
            console.log('scroll top value is: ' + window.scrollTop())
        }
    })
</script>
```